# How do I find all sqlite databases inside a bunch of files without file endings?

Tags: command-line, files, search, file-metadata, sqlite

I have a bunch of files that have just hashes as names and no file endings. (It's an iPhone backup to be precise.) I know there are SQLite databases amongst these files.

How do I find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a starting point using the `file` command to identify the file type:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 file
```

Result:

```
./.X11-unix:                                                                sticky directory
./.Test-unix:                                                               sticky directory
./test.db:                                                                  SQLite 3.x database
```

Then add some grepping to filter out results.

Comment: Probably better to limit to files only. And you may as well tell `find` to run the `file` command, no need for `xargs`: `find . -type f -exec file {} + | grep SQLite`.

Comment: This is a good point, but `xargs` and `-exec` are not exact equivalents - I understand that `-exec` could fail if the argument list is too long (too many files found). *"When you use -exec to do the work you run a separate instance of the called program for each element of input. So if find comes up with 10,000 results, you run exec 10,000 times. With xargs, you build up the input into bundles and run them through the command as few times as possible, which is often just once."* Source: [xargs vs. exec {}](https://danielmiessler.com/blog/linux-xargs-vs-exec/)

Comment: @Anonymous, terdon terminated the `-exec` with `+`: "_This  variant  of  the  -exec action runs the specified command on the selected files, but the command line is built by appending each selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of  the command  will  be  much  less than the number of matched files._"  from `man find`.   Or the `man` page from OSX: "_Same as -exec, except that ``{}'' is replaced with as many pathnames as possible for each invocation of utility.  This behaviour is similar to that of xargs(1)._"

Comment: What user4556274 said. Also, `find` will never fail if there are too many files. When using `;` instead of `+`, the warning you quoted simply explains it will run as many processes as there are files, but it runs them sequentially and separately so there is no issue about the argument list ever being too long.

Answer (score 1):

The utility `file` identifies files based on their magic number and other identifying characteristics.

```
file <filename>
```

will output something like

```
<filename>: SQLite 3.x database
```

To obtain all sqlite3 database files in a directory, you could do something like

```
file * | grep SQLite
```